# Parse http json request based on a field in json

Tags: go

I want to decode an incoming JSON payload of a POST request using the `Decode()` function from `encoding/json`

However, I have a case where the body of the JSON can be different for the same http request. I want to differentiate this body based on a field embedded in the JSON. How can I extract this singular field in Go? For instance, I want the following logic-

```
type BaseObj struct {
        Version string
}

type v1Object struct {
        BaseObj
        Name string
}

type v2Object struct {
        BaseObj
        Name string
        Address string
}

// Somehow extract the 'version' from JSON (req.Body)
if version == "v1" {
        var data v1Object
        json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&data)
} else {
        var data v2Object
        json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&data)
}
```

How can I get the 'version' field embedded in the body?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give some example of those different JSON request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this issue:

### Solution 1: Core Library Way

By only using the core library, you may do this:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // read body content first to reuse
    type protoData struct {
        Version string `json:"version"`
    }
    proto := protoData{}
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(content)).Decode(&proto)

    // version switch
    if proto.Version == "v1" {
            var data v1Object
            json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(content)).Decode(&data)
            // ... do something with data
    } else {
            var data v2Object
            json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(content)).Decode(&data)
            // ... do something with data
    }

}
```

### Solution 2: lzjson Way

I've written a silly library, [lzjson](https://github.com/go-restit/lzjson), to make the code cleaner.

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "github/go-restit/lzjson"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    jsonBody := lzjson.Decode(r.Body)
    version := jsonBody.Get("version").String()
    if version == "v1" {
        var data v1Object
        jsonBody.Unmarshal(&data)
        // ... do something with data
    } else {
        var data v2Object
        jsonBody.Unmarshal(&data)
        // ... do something with data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type BaseObj struct {
        Version string
}

type v1Object struct {
        BaseObj
        Name string
}

type v2Object struct {
        BaseObj
        Name string
        Address string
}

var response map[string]string


json.Unmarshal(req.Body, &response)

if response["version"] == "v1" {
        var data v1Object
        json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&data)
} else {
        var data v2Object
        json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&data)
```

total solution is not good but this is the way you could use data

Comment: The type `req.Body` is a `io.Reader` implementation, which is only designed to be read once. So this implementation will fail at the `json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&data)` statement because you have already `Unmarshal` it earlier.

Comment: @KoalaYeung that is exactly what I had observed before I posted the Q here. thanks for your help!

Comment: io.ReadFull(r Reader, buf []byte) (n int, err error)   with this func you should convert reader to []byte